# Facebook Like Button does not show up at the end of my posts [Sharebar]

Tags: php, facebook, iframe, wordpress

There seems to be a problem with my Sharebar, but the problem can easily be fixed if someone could let me know what is wrong with the code.

I am trying to place a horizontal facebook like box at the end of my posts on my website. My Twitter and Google+ buttons are working fine, except for Facebook. I insert the php codes in my single.php file, and Facebook is the only one that is **blank.**

Here is the iframe code for the Facebook Like "Small Button":

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=[url]&layout=button_count&show_faces=false&width=85&action=like&colorscheme=light&height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:85px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

The preview for the Facebook buttons found in the Sharebar plugin settings are also blank, compared to the others. Here is a screenshot for clarification:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/h7Bo0ni.png]

And here is how it looks under a post on my website: [image: http://i.imgur.com/H1weqQP.png]
The red circle is where the Facebook Like Button is supposed to be, but it is blank.

Thanks in advance for the help. It will greatly be appreciated!

Comment: please check with firebug is button here or need more width

Comment: Try deleting the Facebook Button and add again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try deleting the Facebook button row and add it again.

It has happened to me in the past and just deleting and adding it again has worked.

Also, your `iframe` code seems fine, but if that doesn't work, consider the alternative below.

By pasting this code alone should make your like button appear.  It works for me.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
```

Make sure you have the JDK loaded prior.

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/